# Detecting mouse click when other key is pressed

Tags: javascript, click, p5.js

I'm trying to make a game, and I'm using WASD controls. You sometimes need to click while moving, but `mouseIsPressed`, `mousePressed()`, and `mouseClicked()` aren't detecting it.

I just need to detect a click while another key is being pressed.

EXAMPLE CODE:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight).mousePressed(function() {
    console.log("mousePressed");
  });
}

function draw() {
  if (keyIsPressed) {
    console.log("keyIsPressed");  // if you press a key, then click, this is still the only thing being logged
  }
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    console.log("mouseIsPressed");
  }
}

function mouseClicked() {
  console.log("mouseClicked");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/p5.js"></script>
  <script src="sketch.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that demonstrates what you've tried so far? What exactly do you mean when you say `mouseClicked()` isn't detecting it?

Comment: @KevinWorkman I mean that while I press a key and click, mouseClicked doesn't get called.

Comment: @F4Tornado Please post a [mcve] showing the problem in a small example program.

Comment: @KevinWorkman OK, done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another simple program that demonstrates the problem:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
    background(255, 0, 0);
  if (keyIsPressed) {
    text("keyIsPressed", 100, 100);
    }
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    text("mouseIsPressed", 200, 200);
  }
}
```

Actually, I think this problem is more general than P5.js. Open another program (I used a basic text editor) and hold a key down, then try to move the mouse. For me, my mouse stopped responding whenever I was holding down a key.

Then I googled "holding key prevents mouse from moving" which had a bunch of results, including [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/399341/touchpad-does-not-respond-when-i-am-holding-key-on-the-keyboard). It turns out that the problem is caused by using a trackpad instead of a mouse. Apparently trackpads have settings that disable them when a key is pressed.

Using a "real" mouse works perfectly, in your program and in mine. So the solution is to either change your trackpad settings, or to go get a mouse.

Comment: I use a mouse, and what do you mean by a real mouse?

Comment: @F4Tornado I mean a [trackpad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchpad) versus a [mouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_mouse). Either way this is a system setting and not a P5.js thing.

Comment: 1. I thought you meant real mouse as opposed to a fake mouse. 2. I changed some settings and it worked. 3. that would explain some problems I had with playing other games. 4. the answer is unsatisfying, but it's probably right.

Answer (score -2):

In the following code, i can see mouse and key simultaneously

```
    function setup() {
        createCanvas(100, 100);
        background(51);
    }

    function draw() {
        if (keyIsPressed) {
            if(key=="w"){
                print("w")
            } else if(key=="a"){
                print("a")
            } else if(key=="s"){
                print("s")
            } else if(key=="d"){
                print("d")
            }
            if (mouseIsPressed) {
                print("clic");
            }
        } else if (mouseIsPressed) {
            print("clic")
        }
    }
```

is this working for you ?

Comment: It works only if you click first, which my code already does. You also can't press multiple keys at the same time (you can use keyIsDown() to do that).

Comment: ok. for me it works also when I press a key first. What browser are you using ?